# How to flatten the results of an RDD.groupBy() from (key, [values]) into (key, values)?

Tags: pyspark

From an RDD of key-value pairs like

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 6)]
```

I would like to obtain an RDD of tuples like

```
[(1, 3), (2, 4, 6)]
```

where the first element of each tuple is the key in the original RDD, and the next element(s) are all values associated with that key in the original RDD

I have tried this

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:[item for item in x]).collect()
```

which gives

```
[(1, [3]), (2, [4, 6])]
```

but it is not quite what I want. I don't manage to "explode" the list of items in each tuple of the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rdd.groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0],*tuple(x[1]))).collect()

Answer (score 0):

Best I came up with is

```
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:[a for a in x]).map(lambda x: tuple([x[0]]+x[1])).collect()
```

Could it be made more compact or efficient?